# visual studio code JavaScript code completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Trying to use the Microsoft VS code to develop node.js app.
I'm starting with deciding if it worth the effort of learning this new IDE (new for me). so for now i am not asking about node.js completion rather my own objects.

I read about adding code completion for different packages, but my problem is much more basic.

I can't get code completion for my own JS objects.
Lets say i have this simple object:

```
function User() {
    this.name = '';
}

var me = new User();
me. ????
```

when trying to get to the name property of User after instantiating it there is no code completion for the object properties.

It is something i am doing wrong or is it a basic problem?

to be clear. i am getting code completion for the node.js classes built in JS objects.

It has some really great things built in it but i can't find a solution for this basic problem.

10x

Comment: VSCode only seems to be able to autofill keywords that are declared as part of the code's syntax, rather than its runtime state. To try to explain, `User.state` exists as a result of `this.name = ''`, a run-time action. By contrast, `me` exists syntactically because of `var me` and could not "conditionally exist" or have possibly been removed at some other point. You CAN get around this by creating TypeScript definition files for commonly-used code (You do not necessarily need to work 100% in TypeScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that VSCode does not detect this pattern. If you would use a ES6 class:

```
class User {
    constructor() {
       this.name = '';
    }
}
var me = new User();
me. // now proposes name
```

Comment: I posted an an issue to [vscode/typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7370)